# Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. APT-GET Problem

Tags: apt

I am new to Ubuntu, I am unable to install any application through apt-get install. Please Help. When I do an

```
sudo-apt-get update
```

[Screenshot of terminal Ubuntu 16.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMtAB.png)

it gives the following error. !
Thanks in advance, Please Help. !

I have seen some internet suggestions for this problem, like

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

but they did not work for me.